# Sphinx indexer speed

Tags: amazon-ec2, sphinx, indexer

I have the following issue:
I try to index **same table** with **same data** and **same config** on 2 servers.

First is local machine (Not very good).
Second is Amazon EC2 General-purpose M1 medium insance.

The search results differs almost twice:

Local:

```
collected 84208 docs, 7.6 MB
sorted 54.9 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 84208 docs, 7646878 bytes
total 27.188 sec, 281252 bytes/sec, 3097.17 docs/sec
total 3 reads, 0.177 sec, 99835.0 kb/call avg, 59.2 msec/call avg
total 1013 writes, 7.735 sec, 679.4 kb/call avg, 7.6 msec/call avg
```

Amazon:

```
collected 84208 docs, 7.6 MB
sorted 54.9 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 84208 docs, 7646878 bytes
total 52.111 sec, 146740 bytes/sec, 1615.92 docs/sec
total 3 reads, 1.270 sec, 99833.9 kb/call avg, 423.4 msec/call avg
total 1010 writes, 6.980 sec, 680.8 kb/call avg, 6.9 msec/call avg
```

Does anybody have a clue what can be a reason for such results?
Do I need to run some specific option on Amazon for Sphinx server?

Comment: The indexing speed is nearly identical, the difference is the read speed. What source are you reading from? Is there any network latency involved in the read?

Comment: I have SQL and Sphinx server running on singe insnace.

Comment: What does CPU usage look like when you are running the indexer? You do have to keep in mind that most instances are capped at CPU speeds much lower than what current CPUs are capable of. 1 ECU is the computing power equivalent of a 2007 1-1.2 Ghz Xeon.